# JavaScript onclick function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been troubling problems by using Javascript onclick function. When I click function, I get function not defined but function is defined.
Here is my code

```
<a href="#" onclick="return hello(page);">Hello</a>
```

Here is my JS code

```
  function hello(page){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(resp){
      $('#page_content').html(resp.html);
    });
  }
```

Here is my html file generated by js

```
  function get_pagination(div,total){
    resp = '<ul class="pagination">';
    for(var i =1 ; i<= total; i++ ){
      resp += '<li><a href="#" class="links" onclick= "return hello('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>';
    }
    resp += '</ul>';
    $(div).html(resp);
 }
```

Comment: Most likely your `hello` function is not defined in the global scope. Perhaps it's in a `.ready()` callback.

Comment: I have added my html file @ShyA

Comment: The code you provided works exactly as expected. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: do some basics on w3school.com

Comment: working example https://jsbin.com/qakosibulu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 3):

Just put hello() function outside ready function and declared as global scope . It works.

Answer (score -1):

try to delet   "return" and ";"

```
 resp += '<li><a href="#" class="links" onclick= "return hello('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>';
```

Final

```
  resp += '<li><a href="#" class="links" onclick= "hello('+i+')">'+i+'</a></li>';
```

Comment: it's not the problem.. https://jsbin.com/folagoyesi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Removing the `return` or the semi colon would have no effect. The code is valid either way.